# Instant Apps not active on Oreo devices

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

Instant Apps from the Play Store appear not to be testable on Oreo devices. I have seen posts that indicated problems in Sept and Dec of 2017. Does anyone have any idea of when we can expect resumption?

Comment: I have the same issue. It was working fine in May before updating my mobile in August. Have you found any work around?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Android documentation:

> Instant Apps [Works on the latest Android
>   devices](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/#works-on-the-latest-android-devices)
>   Android Instant Apps supports the latest Android devices from Android
>   5.0 (API level 21) through Android 8.0 (API level 26).

Comment: Using an Oreo device, please search for "buzzfeed". Scroll down to find the entry w/ the "Install" button. Press the entry (not the Install button) to see the IA entry in Play Store.   N.B. There is no Try Now button.   Now repeat, as I just did, on an Android version 7.0 and you will see the Try Now button.

Comment: The reason there is no Try Now button on the Oreo device is probably due to the fact that Google Play Services for Instant Apps is not in the list of Apps. That is because the Settings>Google>Instant Apps switch is not accessible. I am taken to Instant Apps preferences where I select a Google Account but then the Play plugin is not downloaded -- apparently Instant Apps is disabled for Oreo devices. Hence the question.